# React how to wait for all axios to finish

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, axios, fetch

I want to wait until all axios in useEffect are finished.

UseEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
 
  async function getHomePageContent() {
      
    await HomePageServices.getSliderContent().then((response) => {
      setSliderProduct(response.data);
    });

    await HomePageServices.getRecommendedProducts().then((response) => {
      setRecommendedProducts(response.data);
    });

    await HomePageServices.getMostOrderProducts().then((response) => {
      setMostOrderProducts(response.data);
    });

    await HomePageServices.getMostRatedProducts().then((response) => {
      setMostRatedProducts(response.data);
    });
  }
  
  getHomePageContent().catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
 });

     
  }, []);
```

Class:

```
class HomePageServices{

 async getSliderContent(){
    return await axios.get(baseURL+"/slider")
}    

 async getMostRatedProducts(){
    return await axios.get(baseURL+"/mostRatedProducts")
}    

async getMostOrderProducts(){
    return await axios.get(baseURL+"/mostOrderProduct")
}

 async getRecommendedProducts(){
    return await axios.get(baseURL+"/recommendedProduct")
}
}
```

Can someone explain to me how to wait for all axios to end, and if one failed, how to find out which one it was?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) which takes an iterable (e.g. array) of promises and resolves into array of results of each of them.

Results are represented as objects with `status` key, which can be `rejected` or `fulfilled`. The second key of the object is either `value` containing the resolved value, or `reason` in case promise was rejected.

Taking this, then your code in useEffect might be something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {

  const getHomePageContent = async () => ({
    const promises = [
       HomePageServices.getSliderContent(),
       HomePageServices.getRecommendedProducts(),
       HomePageServices.getMostOrderProducts(),
       HomePageServices.getMostRatedProducts()
    ];

    const data = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
    const [slider, recommended, mostordered, mostrated] = data;

    // result for each of promise
    console.log(slider); // { status: 'fulfilled', value: 123 }
    console.log(recommended) // { status: 'rejected', reason: 'blah'}
  });

  getHomePageContent().catch((er) => console.log(er))
}, [])
```